# .Net 6 not running more than two HostedServices

Tags: .net, blazor-server-side

After updating to .Net 6, my hosted service make trouble having more than two hosted services registered:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Server has already started.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<StartAsync>d__29`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Test.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

You can reproduce it creating a new Blazor Server App and just add three empty Background-Services like this one:

```
public class TestService1 : Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
    }
}
```

As I add more than two hosted services in the startup class, starting the application crashes with the exception above.

```
services.AddHostedService<TestService1>();
```

Does anyone has an idea what's wrong? I'm running .Net 6 Preview 5.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research, I found this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/known-issues.md#net-runtime
You can just use following workaround until Microsoft fixes this issue in the next .Net Preview

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseDefaultServiceProvider(o =>
{
    o.ValidateOnBuild = false;
});
```